# Using beginning of TLS ecnrypted data to reveal secret

Tags: tls, encryption, known-plaintext-attack

I have the following question about TLS security:

Assume TLS-PSK protected HTTP with AES256-CBC cipher. 
When a TLS connection is established, client sends some encrypted data, where the
plaintext is well known to an attacker.

For example, it can be a HTTP request, like:

```
GET /some_resource HTTP/1.1
...
```

Can an attacker use intercepted ciphertext and known plaintext it to reveal the secret key?

Does TLS have any features to protect from that?

Comment: `Does TLS have any features to protect from that` Yes... AES!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question boils down to, "Are there known-plaintext attacks against AES-256-CBC?" The answer is: No, no such attacks better than brute force are known. This would constitute a catastrophic break in AES-256-CBC, and *any* cipher broken in such a way would be abandoned rapidly.